# ¿Cómo puedo volcar el resultado de una función en una variable en BASH?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

function square()
{
    let y=$x*$x
    return $y
}

x=3
sqr=square
echo "The square of $x is $sqr"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las funciones en bash lo único que devuelven es el estado final de la ejecución, el *exit status* del último comando ejecutado.

Por tanto tienes dos opciones: guardar en una variable global el resultado, o guardar su *output*:

```
function myfunc(){
   myresult='algo'
}

myfunc
echo $myresult
```

o

```
function myfunc()
{
    local  myresult='algo'
    echo "$myresult"
}

result=$(myfunc)   # o result=`myfunc`
echo $result
```

Comment: Lo que buscaba exactamente era la segunda opción que me has dado, muchas gracias

Comment: Las funciones sí devuelven algo: un código de estado. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la información, lo añado a la respuesta